# iOS compatibility with Swift's String .isEmpty

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, compatibility

What compatibility issues, if any, are there with using `isEmpty` on a string in Swift?

```
let str = "Hello, planet"

if !str.isEmpty {
    print(str)
}
```

I'm developing with the latest Xcode+Swift versions, but I thought I once read (perhaps incorrectly) that `.isEmpty` will not work with older versions of iOS, and so `str == ""` should be used instead.

Thanks!

**References (whose overlap confuses me some):**

- [(String) "whether a string has no characters" ... From Protocol: Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2946268-isempty)
- [(String) "whether the collection is empty"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1539462-isempty)
- [(Range) "whether the collection is empty" ... SDK: Xcode 10+](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/3018235-isempty)

Comment: I tested with iOS9 it's still working

Comment: It's *incorrect*. `isEmpty` is available since Swift 1 regardless whether String was treated as collection or not.

Comment: @vadian The documentation says that `isEmpty` is part of the Collection protocol, supported from Xcode 9.3+. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2946268-isempty

Comment: @DV It doesn't matter, as I said String `isEmpty` exists since Swift 1

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? Does this also happen in Simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The availability of `isEmpty` to check if a String is empty came into Swift, when [String became a collection type](https://www.raywenderlich.com/582-what-s-new-in-swift-4) with the release of **Swift 4**. So the `isEmpty` check on a **String** is quite similar to the `isEmpty` check on an **Array**, **Dictionary** or a **Set**.

And, features like these are not limited to the iOS or Xcode versions. These kind of changes are specific to the language version (Swift); so you can safely assume that it would work on all devices or OS which can run your application.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. The link helps as well. I'm not sure where I got that information from, but I couldn't find anything definitive about compatibility. 

Answer (score 2):

In the recent / latest version of Swift, you can just use the `isEmpty`, and it's the same with comparing `== ""`.

> but I thought I once read (perhaps incorrectly) that .isEmpty will not
>   work with older versions of iOS

The iOS/MacOS version is NOT related to the Swift version you are using (and you should use always the latest), and instead, some of the new provided APIs in Swift do support a minimum version of the iOS/MacOS. So don't be confused.